# OAuth to Azure fails with invalid_grant

Tags: ms-office, preview

I've been trying to use the Office 365 APIs Preview, but I can't get the OAuth authentication to work.

I get to the step where I receive the code in the callback. 
But when I try to trade the code to get a access token as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx)

It fails with:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS70000: The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.\\r\\nTrace ID: 48d94ac6-69d1-4232-96b1-158994428c25\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 2fcade34-489a-4bd5-96d3-47f7aeb3aabf\\r\\nTimestamp: 2014-05-14 21:16:24Z","error_codes":[70002,70000],"timestamp":"2014-05-14 21:16:24Z","trace_id":"48d94ac6-69d1-4232-96b1-158994428c25","correlation_id":"2fcade34-489a-4bd5-96d3-47f7aeb3aabf"}'
```

I'm using `grant_type=authorization_code`.

Anyone know what `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest update to Office 365 APIs preview detailed [here](http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/)?

We have released client libraries (alpha release) for all the available services, including authentication.

Authentication is as simple as:

```
// Shows UI to authenticate
Authenticator = newAuthenticator();
AuthenticationInfo result = await authenticator.AuthenticateAsync("https://outlook.office365.com");
```

And then you can access data, for example, for the above which authenticates with Exchange resource Id:

```
// Obtain calendar event data
var eventsResults = await (from i in client.Me.Events
                 where i.End >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                 select i).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
```

Can you try using the new client libraries to see if you are able to successfully authenticate and get your data?

Comment: I had not seen the new libraries, thanks for pointing them out. I'll checkout the Javascript one. 

I did find my issue, the call to https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token was missing the state parameter in redirect_uri.

Comment: Is there a Javascript API for this that can be used in a Browser?  I'm not looking for a Cordova solution here.  It seems there is very little support for developers outside of the .Net APIs.